# How to fix "invalid version" and "could not read Username" in "go get" of a private repository?

Tags: git, go

I want to use private repositories that are hosted at GitHub in another GoLang-project.

What I did:

1. I created a private access token at my GitHub account settings
2. did then:

   git config --global url."https://xxxxxx:ACCESS_TOKEN@github.com".insteadOf "https://github.com"

with "xxxxxx" as my real GitHub username and then the proper ACCESS_TOKEN.

3. `go get github.com/private/repo`

However, I get always the following error:

```
go: downloading github.com/xxxxxxxx/yyyyyyyyy-go-sdk v0.0.0-20200307154628-cbcb73911013
go get github.com/xxxxxxxx/yyyyyyyyy-go-sdk: github.com/xxxxxxxx/yyyyyyyyy-go-sdk@v0.0.0-20200307154628-cbcb73911013: verifying module: github.com/xxxxxxxx/yyyyyyyyy-go-sdk@v0.0.0-20200307154628-cbcb73911013: reading https://sum.golang.org/lookup/github.com/xxxxxxxx/yyyyyyyyy-go-sdk@v0.0.0-20200307154628-cbcb73911013: 410 Gone
    server response:
    not found: github.com/xxxxxxxx/yyyyyyyyy-go-sdk@v0.0.0-20200307154628-cbcb73911013: invalid version: git fetch -f origin refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* in /tmp/gopath/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/5eca4f397ed3a418f58ee864965ed24936e21268780304d6941f5b3983d31ad1: exit status 128:
        fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

I have also tried the following:

GONOSUMDB=github.com/myusername go get github.com/xxxxxx/yyy...

And according to some answers at StackOverflow for similar issues I tried to add ".git" after the repo-url. But this won't work at all.

What could this be and how can I fix this?

Versions:

```
♠ git --version
git version 2.25.0
hub version 2.14.2
```

♠ go version 1.14

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You did almost everything right, and only forgot one important step.

You need to tell Go to not check checksums, as you are operating on your own private repositories:

```bash
    go env -w GOPRIVATE=github.com/mycompany/*
```

Replace `mycompany` with your username on github or the name of your company and `go get` will most likely work as expected.

Comment: Nobody mentions this in any of the articles or docs or stackoverflow answers til this point (2+ hours of looking by a fairly accomplished google search user) - the fact that this is required is a joke.

Comment: If you check point 5 of this tutorial it teaches the interesting "go mod edit -replace" command which tells Go to search locally for one's own modules. https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/call-module-code

Comment: I had to add quotes to keep my shell (zsh) from trying to expand the glob pattern (*):

`go env -w "GOPRIVATE=github.com/mycompany/*"`

Comment: It would be nice if there was a cross-reference in this answer to the golang documentation that describes the machinery that is being configured: the why and how.

Comment: Other articles fail to mention this little detail, and to me, what was missing was the wildcard. Uggghhhh, I spent at least 3 hours trying to figure this stuff out. Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

I have a solution that might help. this problem occurs in Golang version above 1.13. This happens when we use a private module in our project. Due to the Go Get command run, the golang will do a proxy checksum.
So the alternative is you need to add `GOPRIVATE` environment in your environment.

```
export GOPRIVATE="github.com/private/repo"
```

Or if it doesn't work, try adding with `GONOPROXY` environment.

```
export GONOPROXY="github.com/private/repo"
```

Comment: For me combining the two answers worked.

Answer (score 7):

This may help someone else, but I was getting this error on a public repo. I ran `go clean -modcache` and was able to pull afterwards. Not really sure what the issue was, but could be some sha commit collision in local cache.